# tcltk R - how to access value returned by function

Tags: r, tk-toolkit, rgui

I just started with `tcltk` and `R`. And I am having troubles accessing a computed value by a function called `myFun1` when calling a second function `myFun2`:

Here is a simplified version of my UI:

## Simple tcltk interface

```
library(tcltk)
tt <- tktoplevel()
    topMenu <- tkmenu(tt)
    tkconfigure(tt, menu = topMenu)
    fileMenu <- tkmenu(topMenu, tearoff = FALSE)
        tkadd(fileMenu, "command", label = "Function1", command = myFun1)
        tkadd(fileMenu, "command", label = "Function2", command = myFun2)
        tkadd(topMenu, "cascade", label = "Tab", menu = fileMenu)
tkfocus(tt)
```

## My functions

```
myFun1 <- function() { 
    compVal <- 2*3
    compVal
}

myFun2 <- function() { 
    msg <- paste("The value is: \n", compVal )
    mbval<- tkmessageBox(title="This is the title",
                     message=msg,type="yesno",icon="question")
}
```

Calling `myFun1` works, but `myFun2` returns

> Error in paste("The value is: \n", compVal) : 
>     Object 'compVal' not found

Also wrapping `compVal` into `return(compVal)` doesn`t work.
I was also thinking of doing:

```
res <- list(compVal=compVal)
```

but I am not able to access the created list with `myFun2`. 
Any sugesstions on how to access the returned value form `myFun1` inside `myFun2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, at first I thought its not really a "clean" way of doing it, but even in the offical documentation it is done this way. 
Simply create a global variable using `<<-` :

```
myFun1 <- function() { 
    compVal <<- 2*3
}
```